# Are you able to put an array into a business method in Java

Tags: java, arrays

My main method has to have an array of 2 team names and I wanted to know if there was a way to use the array in the business class and then bring it over to the tester class to set the names.

```
//instance variables
String[] names = new String[2];
int[] score;

//no-arg constructor
    public ReHW3Biz() {
        names[0] = "Null";
        names[1] = "Null";
        score[] = 0;
    }

//getters and setters
public String[] getName(String[] names)
{
    this.names = names;
}
```

the error message I'm getting is:

> This method must return a result of type String[]

Comment: Have you tried 2D array?

Comment: What do you mean by `they didn't work` ? Can you share the sample input and output values?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that it can't be resolved to a type @Vimukthi_R

Comment: I'm in eclipse and it's giving me the red error underlines. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Can you share the exact error message with bit more code? how are you getting the array and how are you calling this method with that array?

Comment: I can! Do I add it into the comments or do I edit the question? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Please edit the question

Comment: The return type your method is `String[]` but there is not `return` statement in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getName method's return type is String[]. so you need to return an array.

```
public String[] getName(String[] names)
{
    this.names = names;
    return this.names;
}
```

But it's better to use setter method to set names value and getter method to get values.

```
public String[] getName() {
    return this.names;
}
public void setName(String[] names) {
    this.names = names;
}
```